# Template argument deduction failure with new expression

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I'm working on a variadic class template but I cannot use it with a new expression without specifying the template arguments (I don't want to). I reduced the problem to the following code sample:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(T p)
        : m(p)
    {}

    T m;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct Bar
{
    Bar(T1 p1, T2 p2)
        : m1(p1), m2(p2)
    {}

    T1 m1;
    T2 m2;
};

int main()
{
    double p = 0.;

    auto stackFoo = Foo(p);       // OK
    auto heapFoo = new Foo(p);    // OK

    auto stackBar = Bar(p, p);    // OK
    auto heapBar = new Bar(p, p); // error: class template argument deduction failed

    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) the compiler should be able to deduce the template arguments in every cases above. I can't figure out why there is no error with `heapFoo` too.

So am I missing something here?

I'm using gcc 7.2.0 on Xubuntu 17.10 with -std=c++17 flag.

Comment: Compiler bug. Couldn't find a dupe, filed [85883](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85883).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug 85883 titled: ["class template argument deduction fails in new-expression"](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85883) filed by Barry has been fixed for GCC 9.

The error does not appear in GCC Trunk ([DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/KERkYr)).

As a workaround for GCC 7.2, you can use value initialization form like below.  ([DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/M-vJJ0)):

```
auto heapBar = new Bar{p, p};
```